# Marklogic 8 pathRangeQuery with namespace in javascript

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9, sjs

I need to build a pathRangeQuery for a path with namespace. This is possible in MarkLogic 9 by using the [`cts.rangeQuery`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.rangeQuery) and building a `cts.reference`. 
Ex ML9 :

```
var qname = fn.QName("http://mynamespace.com/example","name");
var elRef = cts.elementReference(qname, ["type=string", "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"]);
var q = cts.rangeQuery(elRef,'>=','myname');
```

Unfortunately, I can't find the equivalent in MarkLogic 8.

Do you have an idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, `cts:range-query` and `cts.rangeQuery` were introduced in MarkLogic 9. In older versions you need to use the more specific range-query functions, like:

http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/cts.pathRangeQuery

and

http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/cts.elementRangeQuery

When using namespaces however, the latest note is to use `cts.rangeQuery` instead of `cts.pathRangeQuery`. That is not an option with MarkLogic 8. With XQuery, you could have just declared a namespace in your XQuery code, and you would have been good, but that is not an option in SJS either.

You'll need to declare the namespace on app-server or group level to make it work in MarkLogic 8.

HTH!

Comment: Ok, but how to create a pathRangeQuery on an element with a namespace. The $path-expression is a string so I can't write book/myns:name such as myns is http://mynamespace.com/example ?

Comment: You typically predefine `path-namespaces` on the server, and then use the exact same `path-expression` string as in the index configuration.

Comment: I've configured my DB as follows :

1- in path namespaces, I added a ns :
   - prefix: myns
   - namespace uri: http://mynamespace.com/example

2- in range path indexes, I added an index
   - type: string,
   - path expression : myns:book/myns:name
   - collation : http://marklogic.com/collation/

3-  The js statement `var rq = cts.pathRangeQuery("myns:book/myns:name","=","xxx");` return an error **[javascript] XDMP-UNBPRFX: var rq = cts.pathRangeQuery("myns:book/myns:name","=" -- Prefix myns has no namespace binding**

Comment: It is the bit about `When using namespaces however ...`. Try reloading the page if you don't see it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So do you mean that, in ML8, there is no way to define a pathRangeQuery with a declared namespace in SJS?

Comment: You cannot pass in namespace declarations into the pathRangeQuery call, but you can still pre-declare the namespaces on MarkLogic itself to make it work. Just declare them on server or group level, rather than database. The only catch is that you need to use a prefix know to the server, but that shouldn't be a big hurdle..

Comment: Thanks, it works with the NS declaration server side .